# Polar plots 1st quadrant

Tags: pstricks, polarplot

I'm trying to plot some polar vectors using PSTricks but I'm not able to only plot the first quadrant of a polar plot.

This is my current trivial code:

```
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\SpecialCoor
  \psaxes[axesstyle=polar,xAxisLabel=some,subticklinestyle=dashed, subticks=2](5,5)
\psline[linecolor=red, linewidth=2pt]{->}(0,0)(5;15)
\psline[linecolor=red, linewidth=2pt]{->}(0,0)(2;40)
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}
```

Are there some additional parameters I need to pass or it would be better to use another approach to achieve the same result?
[image]

Comment: I do not really understand your problem. Why can't you use something like `\psline(2;-10)(2;140)` ??

Comment: @Herbert I guess he wants to restrict the polar plot from `0°` to `90°`

Comment: ah, understood! I'll change the code in `pst-plot`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `pst-plot.tex` from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-plot/ and then `\psaxes[axesstyle=polar](5,90)`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}    
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(5.75,5.75)
  \psaxes[axesstyle=polar,xAxisLabel=some,subticklinestyle=dashed, subticks=1](5,90)%% for the second example it is (5,180)
\psline[linecolor=red, linewidth=2pt]{->}(0,0)(5;15)
\psline[linecolor=red, linewidth=2pt]{->}(0,0)(2;40)
\psline[linecolor=red, linewidth=2pt]{->}(2;10)(2;85)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Comment: Hi Herbert. In the manual, p. 80, there are `????` in the macro in the box at the top of the page, and `sin` and `cos` (just below) should be `\sin` and `\cos`.

Comment: The `????` should be changed into one of the several existing plot macros

Comment: I see. Good to know. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

Just another solution with `\circ` attached to avoid getting confusion whether or not the angle in degree, radian, gradian, or my own unit (1 donut is a unit of a plane angle defined as 1/e of a turn).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\psset{linecap=1}
\SpecialCoor
\newpsstyle{help}{linestyle=dashed,linecolor=lightgray}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
    \multido{\r=.5+1.0}{5}{\psarc[style=help](0,0){\r}{0}{90}}
    \multido{\i=15+30}{3}{\psline[style=help](5;\i)}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{6}{\psarc(0,0){\i}{0}{90}\uput[-90](\i,0){\i}\uput[180](0,\i){\i}}
    \multido{\i=0+30}{4}{\psline(5;\i)\uput{7pt}[\i](5;\i){$\i^\circ$}}
    \psset{linecolor=red,arrows=->,linewidth=2\pslinewidth}
    \psline(5;15)
    \psline(2;40)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Don't worry I will upvote you also since _Units_ matter most :)

Comment: @texenthusiast: Hello, there is a good news for those who love PSTricks more than his/her parents. :-) I just found a good quick reference titled Visual PSTricks 2.10 by Jean Pierre Casteleyn. Hopefully this information is not only surprising for you but also useful for others.

Comment: +1 For the reference to [Visual PSTricks](http://gte.univ-littoral.fr/sections/stage-latex). :)

Answer (score 4):

By the way, other solution using **TikZ** and **pgfplots**.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar,arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
        \begin{polaraxis}[%
            xmin=0,
            xmax=90,
            ymax=5,
            xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^{\circ}$,
            ytick={0,1,2,3,4},
            yticklabel style={yshift=-13pt},
            grid=both,
            minor grid style={dashed,black!25},
            major grid style=black,
            minor tick num=1]
            \addplot[->,red,very thick] plot coordinates {(0,0) (15,5)};
            \addplot[->,red,very thick] plot coordinates {(0,0) (40,2)};
        \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]